# Addressing prolonged high matrix profile values in anomaly detection

Tags: time-series, anomaly-detection

In an anomaly detection task, I have a data stream where each new data point is generated every 5 minutes. When a new data point arrives, I compute the matrix profile using Stumpy's [stumpi](https://stumpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#stumpy.stumpi) function. An anomaly is reported if the value of the matrix profile exceeds a certain threshold.

The issue I encounter is that when the first anomaly is detected, the matrix profile remains above the anomaly threshold for approximately WINDOW_SIZE steps. In theory, this could result in potential additional anomalies going undetected during that time period.

For those experienced with matrix profiling, do you have any methods to mitigate these potential negative effects without reducing WINDOW_SIZE?

Answer (score 2):

Inventor of the Matrix Profile here.

I dont understand why this is an issue.

Normally if you detect an anomaly, you would turn off anomaly detection for a while (at least one or two window lengths). You do this because "two" anomalies that are close together are almost certainly the same anomaly.

There are scoring functions that do not reflect that logic, but they are wrong.